# Is this piece of code is correct for UdpClient using Rx-Core

Tags: c#, udp, system.reactive

Is this below code is correct, where I am doing some settings for `UdpClient` and then using `Observable.Using(()`?

Please suggest if there is another way to write it?

```
public static IObservable<UdpReceiveResult> UdpStream()
    {

        return Observable.Defer(() =>
        {
            UdpClient receiverUDP = new UdpClient();
            receiverUDP.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            receiverUDP.EnableBroadcast = true;
            receiverUDP.Client.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
            receiverUDP.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 514));


            return Observable.Using(() => receiverUDP,
                udpClient => Observable.Defer(() =>
                    udpClient.ReceiveAsync().ToObservable()).Repeat());
        });

    }
```

Comment: Is it correct? Why not try out if it works?

Comment: it's working. Just checking if there is a better way.

Comment: I would call `Observable.FromAsync(() => udpClient.ReceiveAsync())` without the `.ToObservable()`.

Comment: @Enigmativity, Thanks!. Could you please full code

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this would belong on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per request in the comments:

```
public static IObservable<UdpReceiveResult> UdpStream()
{
    return Observable.Defer(() =>
    {
        UdpClient receiverUDP = new UdpClient();
        receiverUDP.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        receiverUDP.EnableBroadcast = true;
        receiverUDP.Client.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
        receiverUDP.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 514));

        return
            Observable
                .Using(
                    () => receiverUDP,
                    udpClient =>
                        Observable
                            .Defer(() =>
                                Observable
                                    .FromAsync(() => udpClient.ReceiveAsync()))
                            .Repeat());
    });
}
```

Personally, I'd do it this way:

```
public static IObservable<UdpReceiveResult> UdpStream()
{
    return
        Observable
            .Using(
                () =>
                {
                    UdpClient receiverUDP = new UdpClient();
                    receiverUDP.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
                    receiverUDP.EnableBroadcast = true;
                    receiverUDP.Client.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
                    receiverUDP.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 514));
                    return receiverUDP;
                },
                udpClient =>
                    Observable
                        .Defer(() =>
                            Observable
                                .FromAsync(() => udpClient.ReceiveAsync()))
                        .Repeat());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Much, but we're not using `receiverUDP` into second `Observable`..... `udpClient =>
                    Observable
                        .Defer(() =>
                            Observable
                                .FromAsync(() => udpClient.ReceiveAsync()))
                        .Repeat());'

Comment: @user584018 - I don't understand what you mean? This should be the same query as yours.

Comment: Ok Thanks...please ignore my last comment.